# Joining numbers in array javascript

Tags: javascript

I got different buttons that looks like down below (ranging from 1 to 9)

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculatorNumber(1)">
```

It leads up the following function:

```
function calculatorNumber(i) {
    myNumbers.push(i);
    var x = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = myNumbers.join("");
```

But its not working quite as I'd like it to. If i press number 3 once and then number 4, 3 & 4 is stored in the array at [0] and [1] however i would like them to be stored at the same place and as 34. Any ideas?

I've tried to enhance the function by the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
  function calculatorNumber(i) {
    myNumbers.push(i);
    var x = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML =  myNumbers.join(""); //joining them together without comma
    myNumbers = []; //then empty the array altogether
    myNumbers.push(x); // and then push the new value in
```

Comment: Use a string instead of an array?

Comment: why does it matter how it is stored? `myNumbers.join("")` will display as `34` as desired...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan because it is a calculator software, the 34 needs to be stored as 34 otherwise the software wants to add 3 + 4 together

Comment: Well, that requirement wasn't specified in the question... The answers given below should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array of numbers. It's just one number:

```
theOneNumber = theOneNumber * 10 + i;
```

So you start with 0.

Press 3 => number is 3

Press 4 => number is 34

Press 5 => number is 345

Comment: No, because it's gonna be more numbers. Say I press 3,4 I want it to be 34. Then the users press + button and then 44, i want the script to add 34 and 44 together.

Comment: Just do an edit: theOneNumber * (i.toString().length*10) + i

Comment: Well then start a new number, when an operator is pressed. I don't see how you want to perform the calculation on the array. Use a string if you want to display the numbers. However, I'll provide another answer that takes this into account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the numbers pushed in. Please delete this line:

```
myNumbers = []; //then empty the array altogether
```

Working example

```js
var myNumbers = [];

function calculatorNumber(i) {
    myNumbers.push(i);
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML =  myNumbers.join("");
}

function cl() {
    myNumbers = [];
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML =  "";
}
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div><br>
<button type="button" onclick="calculatorNumber(1)">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="calculatorNumber(2)">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cl()">CL</button>
```

With numbers

```js
var myNumbers = [0], operator = [];

function calculatorNumber(i) {
    myNumbers[myNumbers.length - 1] = myNumbers[myNumbers.length - 1] *10 + i;
    updateScreen();
}

function cl() {
    myNumbers[myNumbers.length - 1] = 0;
    updateScreen();
}

function plus() {
    operator.push(p);
    myNumbers.push(0);
    updateScreen();
}

function p(b, a) {
    myNumbers.push(a + b);
}

function equal() {
    operator.length && operator.pop()(myNumbers.pop(), myNumbers.pop());
    updateScreen();
}

function updateScreen() {
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML =  myNumbers[myNumbers.length - 1];
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">0</div><br>
<button type="button" onclick="calculatorNumber(1)">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="calculatorNumber(2)">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cl()">CL</button>
<button type="button" onclick="plus()">+</button>
<button type="button" onclick="equal()">=</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry i was very unclear with the question. I later want to add the numbers together. I also got a + button, so say i press 24 and then + 24 i want the script to add the numbers together @Nina Schoz

Answer (score 0):

This solves your immediate problem:

```
 var lastIndex = myNumbers.length - 1;
 myNumbers[lastIndex] = myNumbers[lastIndex] * 10 + i;
```

However, I don't know how you want to handle operators.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to concatenate the numbers in your array and convert them to string on the go.

For example:

```
myNums = [1, 2, 3]
var text = '';

for (i = 0; i < myNums.length; i++) {
    text += myNums[i].toString();
}
```

returns '123'

then:

```
var x = document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = text;
```

Maybe you can split it into two functions:

```
var myNumbers = [];
text = '';

function getMyNumber(i){
    myNumbers.push(i);
    }
function getText(myNumbers){
    for (i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; i++) {
    text += myNumbers[i].toString();
    }
    }
```

Call these functions appropriately (loop through calling first, I don't know how you get the input though, then just call the second with myNumbers as argument) and then populate your 'screen' element. In this case both vars are global.

I hope it helps.